# i am getting this error while connecting to mongodb Atlas: "dns.exception.Timeout: The DNS operation timed out after 30.000985383987427 seconds"

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

i am connecting my Flask app to mongodb atlas using Flask-PyMongo, but i am getting this error.

"dns.exception.Timeout: The DNS operation timed out after 30.000985383987427 seconds"

and after that it says:
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

"pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: The DNS operation timed out after 30.000985383987427 seconds"

Here's the code:

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'FirstCluster'
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb+srv://username:password@firstcluster-bblvc.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true'


mongo = PyMongo(app)

@app.route('/connect')
def connect_to_mongo():
    return 'Connecting to Mongodb'

@app.route('/collections')
def adding():
    user = mongo.db.users
    user.insert({'name' : 'vatsalay'})
    return 'Added User!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: A DNS timeout is probably the result of a networking issue. It could either be transient ( just a passing thing ) or either your machine running the code needs a configuration check that DNS protocols are allowed, or the Atlas instance is not running. Please also ensure you added your client application host address to the whitelist of allowed Atlas clients, or similarly allowed access from that machine.

Comment: you were right, it was just a passing phase.

Comment: I am working on Flask app and I had same issue after I've installed eventlet. But when I uninstalled it, the problem with timeout was gone. Hope this helps someone...

Answer (score 9):

Try using a different connection string. I was having problems with the 3.6 or later string. Simply used the 3.4 or later string and it connected instantly.

if you insist on using a newer connection string, you need to install pymongo srv

For Windows

```
pip install pymongo[srv]
```

For Mac

```
pip3 install pymongo[srv]
```

On zsh

```
pip3 install 'pymongo[srv]'
```

Comment: which os you are using ??

Comment: its nuts that this is actually a perfect solution

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have to install pymongo[srv] to get `mongodb+srv` URI to work. 
Try installing it with `pip3 install 'pymongo[srv]'`

Answer (score 2):

Same problem in Google App Engine standard.

In my case was solution to use older type of URL:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@CLUSTER...
```

SW:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Python 2.7.17 / 2.7.12
- Pymongo 3.11.1
- Google Cloud SDK 319.0.0

Connection from test file directly from os was OK, but same code run from Google SDK dev appserver2 faile.

After change URL generated by cloud.mongodb.com Atlas
in section Cluster -> Connect -> Choose a connection method -> Python - 3.4 or later
connection was established.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use different version of connection string. You can change the version in cluster -> connect -> connect your application.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, it worked for me by changing my dns from automatically to "8.8.8.8".
How?
If you're on Windows, do the following

1. Open Network and internet setting
2. Network and sharing center
3. Press on your internet connection Wi-fi(name of your router)
4. Go for proprieties
5. Choose tcp/ipv4 and go to proprieties again
6. Choose this one and edit it "use the following dns server and choose" 8.8.8.8 (google dns)

Also as Neil Lunn said check the allowed ips

Comment: in my case it was just a passing phase, as @Neil Lunn said earlier. so if any of you guys facing this problem wait for a day and it will be solved. if its just a passing phase.

Answer (score 1):

It might be an error caused while your Mongo Client is unable to find the connection to the server. So, better check you internet connectivity and then run the program

Answer (score 1):

I was using python 3.6.2, so I chose to use the connection string for "3.6 or later". It gave me this error. Later I tried it with the connection string for "3.4 or later". It worked perfectly fine.

Try using the connection string for "3.4 or later".

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I suddenly couldn't connect. All my colleagues were using the same python version etc.

A few days before another colleague had the timeout whilst using their phones wifi. They could connect when they switched to their normal wifi.

After I rebooted my wifi I was able to connect.

It's not a great solution but it's worth trying.

Comment: I'm also facing this issue when connecting with my phone's wifi